# How to disable a button from another activity

Tags: java, android, button, preferences, shared

I have this little **login program** that saves data into shared preferences. The main activity has **"login" and "account"** buttons. I want to **disable** the login button when shared preferences are null and enable the "account" button for the user to sign up for an account which is my **second activity**. How can I enable/disable 2 buttons if shared preferences are null?

1. Activity 1

   ```
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   setContentView(R.layout.main_interface);

   final Button login = (Button)findViewById(R.id.Login);
   final Button account = (Button)findViewById(R.id.Account);
   login.setEnabled(false);
   login.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
       public void onClick(View arg0) {
           startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, Summation.class));

       }
   });


   account.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
       public void onClick(View arg0) {
           startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, Append.class));
       }
   });
   Button exit = (Button)findViewById(R.id.Exit);
   exit.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
       public void onClick(View arg0) {
           finish();
           System.exit(0);
       }
   });
   ```
2. Activity 2

   ```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Stetho.initializeWithDefaults(this);
    setContentView(R.layout.append_interface);


   final EditText usernameAppend = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.usernameAppend);
   final EditText passwordAppend = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.passwordAppend);

   //this buttons appends the username and password to the SharedPreferences
   Button append = (Button)findViewById(R.id.Append);
   append.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            final SharedPreferences mySharedPref = getSharedPreferences(PREF_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE);
            final SharedPreferences.Editor editor = mySharedPref.edit();
           //Append get data
            final String un = usernameAppend.getText().toString();
            editor.putString(editorUsername,un);
            editor.commit();
            final String pw = passwordAppend.getText().toString();
            editor.putString(editorPassword, pw);
            editor.commit();
           if(mySharedPref != null){
               Toast.makeText(Append.this,"Account saved",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

               startActivity(new Intent(Append.this, MainActivity.class));

           }else{
               Toast.makeText(Append.this,"Please enter again",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

           }

           }

       }
   );
   //Exit button,, exits the app
   Button exit = (Button)findViewById(R.id.Exit);
   exit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
   public void onClick(View arg0) {
       finish();
       System.exit(0);
        }
    });

    }
   ```

Comment: not clear, could you specify a sénario of execution?

Comment: main activity has 3 buttons; login, account, exit. Account button provides the user a sign up activity which appends the username and password into a shared preferences. login button enables if a username and password has been added into a shared preferences. if shared preferences is null, login button is disabled. thanks and my sharedpreferences is declared on my activity 2 extends activity 1

Answer (score 0):

In 1st Activity check either your shared preference exists or not. first time it will be null.

```
     btnLogin.setEnabled(false);
     btnAccount.setEnabled(false);
     SharedPreferences mPrefs=this.getSharedPreferences(Your_Preference_Name,Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    if(mPrefs==null)
    {
        btnAccount.setEnabled(true);
    }
    btnAccount.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

        }
    });
    btnLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

        }
    });
```

Comment: it still has errors because i declared my shared preference in my activity 2. activity 2 extends main activity